# reactjs call a function continuosly after recieving callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component like:

```
class BodyContent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       const { actions } = this.props

        var timerID = setInterval(function() {
            actions.upload_image()
        }, 5000)


    }
```

My `upload_image` function contains `post request` to an api. When response is received I want it to call the function again.

I want to call the function contnuosly only after my `upload_image` has finised successfully.

How cam I able to do this ??

Comment: Wrap you `actions.upload_image()` within an observable. use [rx](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) for that. You could try the [while loop](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/while.md): It should repeat the actions each time `upload_image` has finised successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your upload_image function could return a Promise.

Then you can call again the upload_image function if the promise is fulfilled

```
class BodyContent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
   const { actions } = this.props

   function call_upload_image_continiously() {
       actions.upload_image().then(call_upload_image_continiously);
   }

   call_upload_image_continiously();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get your `upload_image` function to call itself. Note that you wouldn't actually have a `setTimeout`.

```
var actions = {
    uploadImage() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Image has uploaded! Will go again now.');
            actions.uploadImage();
        }, 1000); // setTimeout just to simulate ansynchronousness
    }
}

actions.uploadImage();
```

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/hefaqu/1/edit?js,console